# Decoding JSON file - Expecting EOF

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have a JSON input to parse. The sample looks like the following:

```
{"source":123456,"target":1211251,"distance":1.2115,"type":1}
{"source":223456,"target":1214251,"distance":1.1115,"type":1}
```

An error is thrown with the following code:

```
import json
with open('Data/test.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
```

Error

```
raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 - line 2 column 62 (char 62 - 123)
```

The code manages to parse if only 1 line of sample is given, and throws error if more than 1 line is given in the JSON input.

I check with JSONLint, and the following error is indicated

```
Error: Parse error on line 6:
....2115,   "type": 1} {    "source": 223456,
---------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'
```

Can anyone gives me a hint to solve this error?

Comment: Try Putting Comma between two inputs `{"source":123456,"target":1211251,"distance":1.2115,"type":1}, 
{"source":223456,"target":1214251,"distance":1.1115,"type":1}`

Comment: Apart from this, I need to put [ and ] at the beginning and the end of the file, as mentioned in one of the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file is lots of json, not a single json, so you can parse them for each line.

Sample code:

```
import json
with open('Data/test.json') as data_file:
   for line in data_file:
       data = json.loads(line)
       print(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you source input is

```
{"source":123456,"target":1211251,"distance":1.2115,"type":1}
{"source":223456,"target":1214251,"distance":1.1115,"type":1}
```

then this is not valid JSON. You simply cannot have two objects not being part of i.e. array or other dictionary. So your source data needs fixing not the code in first place.

Comment: Yeah. I doubt it is a design problem. But I got this from another team, so it is out of my control on how they design their output.

Answer (score 1):

JSON string may contain only one, let's say, "first-level" object. That object may contain something inside itself, if it's a dict or a list. But what you are trying to parse is not a valid JSON. Perhaps you want to put your two dicts in a list

```
[
  {"source":123456,"target":1211251,"distance":1.2115,"type":1},
  {"source":223456,"target":1214251,"distance":1.1115,"type":1}
]
```